# Can I use symbols, such as (*,/,&,^), for enum in C?

Tags: c

I want to use enumeration type in C. I know how to use them but I have a question. I have an example like this

```
enum S { A,B,C,G };
```

I know this works but can i do something like this?

```
enum S {^,*,/,%};
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: No, since you can't use them for any identifier

Comment: Try it and see (spoiler: no)

Comment: They are reserved characters.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. Maybe because are reserved characters. Thanks anyway

Comment: There are a C standard documents and numerous reference manuals defining what can be used where in C. Why not to try and read them?

Comment: I will try to read them. I find something but its very difficult for my experience. Thanks anyway for your attention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You can only use alphanumeric characters and underscores in identifiers (variable, function, and type names) in C.  And the identifier cannot start with a number.  Also, you can't use certain reserved keywords.

*http://www.cprogrammingexpert.com/C/Tutorial/fundamentals/identifiers.aspx* (link broken)

UPDATE: Newer link that's not broken:
https://www.w3schools.in/c-programming/identifiers

Comment: In GNU C you can use a [dollar sign](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Dollar-Signs.html) as well.

Comment: The link was helpful. Thank you..!

Answer (score 2):

No. However, you could do something like this:

```
enum S
{ CARET = '^',
  STAR = '*',
  SLASH = '/',
  PERCENT = '%'
};

int foo()
{ enum S somevar = CARET;
  // ....
  if (somevar == PERCENT)
    // ....
}
```

Not sure if that would be useful for whatever it is you're trying to do, though, since you don't really give any background...

Comment: That's exactly what i want! It's very helpful but will increment works on that? I mean I read in a site that you can increment enumaration  types but in your code will it work? Thanks again! (I didn't give any code because i haven't write any yet. It's just an idea for now, something came up in my mind)

Comment: Well, technically, you can increment in such a case, but it may not give you the results you expect. For example, `CARET + 1` is the same as saying `'^' + 1`, which would give `'_'`, assuming an ASCII locale, which strictly speaking is not a valid value of your `enum`. `CARET + 1` will *not* result in `STAR`.

Comment: Yes you're right. It doesn't work because the compiler assign differnet values. For example assigns 47,95,34, etc. Thakns anyway. I will use a function to increment

Comment: If you want to "increment" the characters, just put them together into continuous memory.  In C, this is called a "string" of characters.  For instance: `char S[] = "^*/%";`.  Then you can find the index which matches one of those characters like so: `char* pMatchedChar = strchr(S, (int)somevar;`, which will return NULL if the character is not in the string.  If you want to iterate, just use a for loop: `for (char* pSymbol = S; pSymbol; pSymbol++) { doSomethingWithChar(*pSymbol); }`.

Comment: Or, just forget about an enum.  If you want to see if some value matches, say, the percent sign character, then just compare it to that character, like so: `if (myChar == '%') printf("match\n"); else printf("no match\n);`.

Comment: I just did what you said. Just compare using if-else. I want to use enum for switch specific but anyway. Although your idea about using string is brilliant. If I have int k=0;  p[strlen(p)%k];  k++; And all this in a proper for loop it will give any cell from p. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

The [ANSI C specification](http://eli-project.sourceforge.net/c_html/c.html#m51) says you can use an "OrdinaryIdDef" for enums... so it follows the same rules as--for example--variable & function names

Comment: Thank you very much. The link is really helpful. I will trie to learn something but i think i don't have the experience..